# sinatra api accessing and fetching from database with more than 500k record (Ruby)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have used Ruby, Sinatra framework to implement a web-service API. Used MYSQL for db connection and query.
My ruby code interacts with active record model and fetch records from db.

My database is a dynamic db which grows very fast and updates records very frequently, where I cant use any cache.

Currently, in my database, single table contains more than 500k records. which takes too much time to execute a select query and fetch records from table(containing 500k records which might grow even bigger).

This results and impacts badly on my API (get request). Taking around half an hour to process the API which is a big impact on API performance.

Can anyone please suggest me what tools or any efficient ways to make my API faster.

Comment: Assuming 5 lakhs = 500.000, that is not a very large number of records for a database engine. Still, half an hour is a very long time.. Start with determining what exactly is taking so long: Is it the database or is it the Ruby processing? Then start from there.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRikowski, here is one of my API response, which fetches only 681 records from database. 
{
  "response": {
    "errors": null,
    "record_count": 681,
    "users": [
      {
        "AccountID": "AT-990056454",
        "CompanyDID": "",
        "DTCreated": "2015-02-09T04:11:05.000Z",
        "DTSysCreated": "2015-02-09T04:11:05.000Z"
      },
      --------------- GOES ON UNTIL LAST RECORD--------------

}

here where record_count is more than 1 lakh its taking too much of time.

yea I will monitor which is taking time in my ruby code..

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure its the large number of `ActiveRecord` objects you are creating. If you really want to return half a million records over an API, you shouldn't be using ActiveRecord. The memory consumption alone will cripple your server. You could use background jobs, e.g. delayed_job or perhaps rethink your API.

Comment: Could you please suggest me the best practice to be followed up over here instead of ActiveRecord object?

As I am concerned about the memory conception too and its a production server which is already live. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Another idea: You could try ActiveRecord batches http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html Alternatively you can try using the raw MySQL gem and do all procesing by yourself https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2 But in the end I think it is better to redesign the API itself, i.e. make the client ask for the users in chunks or create the response in a background job on a separate server.

Comment: @DanielRikowski, I have used ActiveRecord batches and I see records duplicated as my table is very dynamic that keeps updating and creating new records.

How could I handle such situation?

Thanks..!!!

Comment: @DanielRikowski, Also our production set up is like, our Sinatra and Ruby code base and the database are in different servers. 
I personally feel that it might take time to connect to db in other server.
Is this the best practice to set up?